# What's the current cost of SRAM?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-hardware

I'm teaching Architecture this semester, and I'm using Computer Organization and Design (Patterson & Hennessy) as the text. The book contains a table that has the typical access time and cost of SRAM, DRAM, flash, and hard disk as of 2012. Costs have come down pretty steeply in the last 4-5 years though, and I'd like to give my students a more up-to-date version. And while I can easily find cost/GB on the other 3 technologies, I'm having a hard time finding an up-to-date cost for SRAM. Can anybody help with that?

Comment: Unfortunately, hardware questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Is there a better place to ask? I asked here because Meta seemed to indicate that this would be the best place.

Comment: Let's wait for the moderators to intervene.

Comment: there is some context/ CS angle wrt moores law. AS suggest you try to describe the topic wrt that. also try [chat]

Comment: "How much do computer parts cost?" isn't computer _science_. I'm sorry that you were mis-advised to ask here.

Comment: @vzn I wouldn't describe Moore's law as computer science, either.

Comment: And the Moore law stopped working, so...

Comment: many/ various scientists/ [encyclopedia brittanica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Moores-law) (etc) consider moores law part of computer science, but there are many others who have a _narrower_ view

Comment: Based on a quick browsing of [Newark](http://www.newark.com/sram), it looks like SRAM *pricing* can vary between about 8 dollars/MiB (for an 8Mibit part) to about 45 dollars/MiB (for a 72Mibit part). (144Mibit was cheaper per bit, only about 27 dollars/MiB.)

Comment: SRAM and DRAM are used for very different applications where their respective strenghts can be leveraged. There is no mass market for gigabit SRAM chips, it is difficult to fairly compare prices. An SRAM bit occupies more area than a DRAM bit, and chip prices are strongly related to their surface (although the process for making DRAM is a bit different from SRAM, because of the storage capacitors)